# Springwebflow + CDI + JSF application on Jboss 7

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, cdi, spring-webflow

I have been trying to get my application working under JBoss 7 but have finally hit a problem that I cannot find an answer to.

The application is a web based application using **springwebflow,cdi,jsf (primefaces)**.

it gets deployed without an error and renders the first page (login.xhtml). once i'm logged in, if i try to click list of accounts (users's accounts) link (which invokes the webflow for list of Accounts) which display a list of accounts but when the server looks for the resource to use for rendering the view, it fails with **FileNotFoundException** when attempting to load a resource as below.  **javax.faces.FacesException: Error Checking Last Modified for jndi:/localhost/datapTest/AccountSelect.xhtml**  For some reason the default view of the flow (Accountflow) is being converted to a jndi resource location.  Can anybody help?

Updated : 
after changing the param javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD value to 1
exception : 
**Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Facelet /accountSelect.xhtml not found at: jndi:/default-host/datapTest/accountSelect.xhtml**

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/asual/summer/commit/89be5f91ac89c49968fcbbb75df3add47beac118)

Comment: thanks for your reply, i changed the value of the "javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD" param to "-1" m but still the same error

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar problem, and i found out that the problem was a conflict with the `omnifaces` lib. The problem occurs because `omnifaces` registers a view handler called `RestorableViewHandler` and this view handler does not know how to solve the id's from the flows files.

To solve that, we need to add the view handler of `spring-webflow` locally on our `faces-config.xml` file:

```
<application>
    <view-handler>org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

**PS: Or you can just remove the `omnifaces` dependence from your application.**